# Empirical Bayes/MCMC references

Tags: bayesian, references, markov-chain-montecarlo, empirical-bayes

I'm interested in references for running empirical Bayes (EB) in conjunction with MCMC. The closest thing I've found to what I'm looking at is a surprisingly recent and somewhat obscure paper [available here](http://www.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~yvesa/EB.pdf), and seems to suggest an improved version of the obvious thing to do (do some kind of stochastic gradient descent based on draws from the Markov chain); the main reference to EB applications given in that paper is to a Casella Biostatistics paper (2001) that suggests doing something unreasonable. There is also another surprisingly recent [Annals paper](http://web.stat.ufl.edu/~doss/Research/caebmbsa.pdf) that does empirical Bayes by attempting to optimize Bayes factors by running multiple chains (this seems to me like overkill, but to be fair I think this isn't the entire point of what they are doing).

Given how long EB has been studied, there's no way there isn't a completely standard solution for doing EB within MCMC that isn't much older than these papers, right? It seems to me like unless you are dealing with a toy problem you would have to deal with this, and it is an old problem, so there should be less obscure papers.

Comment: @Ret I copied wrong URL of paper. I linked to authors we page to get around pay wall issues but linked to the wrong paper by mistake.

Comment: Have you found more references?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much about this topic, but since I found your references very interesting, I felt obliged to give something in return. It appears to me that a reasonable starting point is:

> Carlin, Bradley P.; Louis, Thomas A. (2000). Bayes and Empirical Bayes Methods for Data Analysis (2nd ed.). Chapman & Hall/CRC.

For instance, they mention the following in the Preface

> A principal reason for the ongoing expansion in the Bayes and EB statistical
>   presence is of course the corresponding expansion in readily-available
>   computing power, and the simultaneous development in Markov chain Monte
>   Carlo (MCMC) methods and software for harnessing it. Our desire to
>   incorporate many recent developments in this area provided one main impetus
>   for this second edition. For example, we now include discussions
>   of reversible jump MCMC, slice sampling, structured MCMC, and other
>   new computing methods and software packages.

Best.

Comment: @guy Good, thanks for letting me know. Recall that a $\epsilon$−final version of the papers from IMS is always posted on arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.51600.

Comment: Just wanted to give an update. G-modeling, introduced by Brad Efron, is a faster EB implementation than MCMC offers. He fits a spline to the marginal distribution. See here, https://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/papers/2016G-ModelingProgram.pdf